# pandas sort a column by values in another column

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a dataset that I want to sort and assign rank based on it.

Suppose it has two columns, one is year and the other is the column that I want to sort.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'year': pd.Series([2006, 2006, 2007, 2007]), 
        'value': pd.Series([5, 10, 4, 1])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to sort the column 'value' by each year and then give rank to it. What I would like to have is

```
data2= {'year': pd.Series([2006, 2006, 2007, 2007]), 
        'value': pd.Series([10, 5, 4, 1]),  
        'rank': pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 2]}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)

>>> df2
   rank  value  year
0     1     10  2006
1     2      5  2006
2     1      4  2007
3     2      1  2007
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and then use `rank` (with `ascending=False` to get the largest values first).  You don't need to sort in the `groupby`, as the result is indexed to the dataframe (slightly faster performance).

```
df['yearly_rank'] = df.groupby('year', sort=False)['value'].rank(ascending=False)

>>> df.sort_values(['year', 'yearly_rank'])
   value  year  yearly_rank
1     10  2006            1
0      5  2006            2
2      4  2007            1
3      1  2007            2
```

Comment: Do you really need `transform`? Won't `df.groupby('year')['value'].rank()` do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that is simpler.

Comment: Wow, this is what I was looking for. Big thanks to both of you!

Comment: Good. Is there a way I can sort values in one by another which is having null values? I have tried 4 methods which doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Consider a [groupby apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) function with sort:

```
def rankfct(row):    
    row['rank'] = row['value'].rank(ascending=False)    
    return row

df = df.groupby(['year']).apply(rankfct).sort(['year','value'], ascending=[1,0])
```