# Sort a column so that one column follows the values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a large dataset that represents a hierarchy tree of companies. To give an example, I might have something like the following:

```
Child                 Parent
273500                273500
20574624              273500
2202652               1879450
19933526              1879450
18000796              18352628
18352628              19770000
1359996               20574624
1879450               20574624
18441258              20574624
20637582              20574624
20840426              20574624
20844632              20574624
20934910              20574624
20965442              20574624
21193122              20574624
21194666              21193122
19770000              20574624
19681810              18352628
19931554              20574624
18382902              1879450
19780666              1879450
20631784              20574624
```

As you can see, the first row is the parent node.

What I want to do, is to sort the data in such a way that it actually represents a hierarchy where you start from the top and go to the bottom of the hierarchy. The reason I want to do this is, because I want to calculate the height of the tree. To do this, first I need to contruct the tree. I already know how to construct the tree using the `treelib package`. My problem now is, if I have a large dataset consisting of thousands of rows, how can I order my data in such a way that I am able to build a tree.

What I have already tried is to sort the Parent column by the values in the Child column using the .sort_values in pandas. This, however, did not work the way I wanted it to. I also tried to do this with the group by function and somehow give the rows a certain rank based on this question: [pandas sort a column by values in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347041/pandas-sort-a-column-by-values-in-another-column).

This did not work for the large dataset.

Below is the result that I want to get.

```
Child         Parent
273500        273500   # The first row is the parent row
20574624      273500   # I want all children that belong to this parent node
1879450       20574624 #  
18441258      20574624
19770000      20574624
19931554      20574624
20631784      20574624
20637582      20574624
20840426      20574624
20844632      20574624
20934910      20574624
20965442      20574624
21193122      20574624
2202652       1879450 # Now, I want all the children that belong to 1879450
18382902      1879450 # and so on
19780666      1879450
19933526      1879450
18352628      19770000
18000796      18352628
19681810      18352628
1359996       20574624
21194666      21193122
```

For such a small dataset, one could easily order it by hand. But for large datasets consisting of thousands of rows, this can be a bit cumbersome.

Comment: `df.sort_values(["Parent", "Child"])`?

Comment: @politicalscientist: you are faster than me 4 secs in comment :). I deleted mine

Comment: In this specific example, this solution will work, but in general, if there is a larger dataset where the numbers aren't in a ascending order from tree level to tree level, then it will not work.

I am going to think of a larger example to illustratie this. Unfortunately I can't upload the larger dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the following function:

```
def getDescendants(curr, par, level):
    res = [[curr, par, level]]
    children = df.query('Parent == @curr')
    for n in children.Child:
        if n != par:
            deeper = getDescendants(n, curr, level + 1)
            if len(deeper) > 0:
                res.extend(deeper)
    return res
```

Then get the id of the "Parent of all parents" (from row 0):

```
hd = df.iloc[0, 0]
```

and call the above function:

```
pd.DataFrame(getDescendants(hd, hd, 1), columns=['Child', 'Parent', 'Level'])
```

This function does even more. It gives also the level of each person in the
hierarchy.

## Alternative way to find the "Parent of all parents"

If the "Parent of all parents" may be located in **any** row (not necessarily
in the first), another approach is required.

Assuming that the source DataFrame contains a **single** hierarchy tree,
the root node can be read as: `hd = df.query('Parent == Child').iloc[0,0]`.
Then generate the hierarchy tree as above.

If there are **multiple** hierarchy trees, then:

- `df.query('Parent == Child').iloc[0]` gets a *Series* of "root" ids.
- You have to write a loop for each element from this *Series*, call
  *getDescendants(id, id, 1)* for the current *id* and collect results
  (e.g. as elements of a list).
- Concat them (vertically).

Comment: This works fine indeed. The only disadvantage might be that you have to give the input of the "Parent of all parents." What if it would not have been in row 0 f.e. Just a small thing. Overall, it works amazingly well. Thank you very much. Appreciate it.

Comment: Note that *df.query('Parent == Child')* selects rows for each "root" of hierarchy.
So *iloc[0,0]* takes the initial row (from these rows) and from this row - initial column (person Id).

Comment: I changed the final part of my answer (a little), hope that will answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly want you want is a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), I suggest you use the one implemented in [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/):

```
edges = df[df.child != df.parent].reset_index()
dg = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source='parent', target='child', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
order = list(nx.lexicographical_topological_sort(dg))

result = df.set_index('parent').loc[order, :].dropna().reset_index()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
      parent       child
0     273500    273500.0
1     273500  20574624.0
2   20574624   1359996.0
3   20574624   1879450.0
4   20574624  18441258.0
5   20574624  20637582.0
6   20574624  20840426.0
7   20574624  20844632.0
8   20574624  20934910.0
9   20574624  20965442.0
10  20574624  21193122.0
11  20574624  19770000.0
12  20574624  19931554.0
13  20574624  20631784.0
14   1879450   2202652.0
15   1879450  19933526.0
16   1879450  18382902.0
17   1879450  19780666.0
18  19770000  18352628.0
19  18352628  18000796.0
20  18352628  19681810.0
21  21193122  21194666.0
```

If you want to keep the order of the columns `(['child', 'parent'])` just do:

```
result = df.set_index('parent').loc[order, :].dropna().reset_index().reindex(['child', 'parent'], axis=1)
```

Be sure to import the required libraries:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: I get "Input graph is not a networkx graph type" error.

Could you please tell me what packages I have to import besides networkx?

Comment: I needed to put  "create_using=nx.DiGraph()" The brackets after DiGraph did the trick.

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you didn't accept this answer as correct one? @Eren

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to do this in vanilla Python rather than using pandas. Basically what you want to do is construct a set of trees and then walk them from the root nodes in these trees.

Lets say you've already parsed the data and you can start with some list `processes` of structure `List[Tuple[int, int]]`.

```
processes = [
    (273500, 273500),
    (20574624, 273500),
    (2202652, 1879450),
    (19933526, 1879450),
    (18000796, 18352628),
    (18352628, 19770000),
    (1359996, 20574624),
    (1879450, 20574624),
    (18441258, 20574624),
    (20637582, 20574624),
    (20840426, 20574624),
    (20844632, 20574624),
    (20934910, 20574624),
    (20965442, 20574624),
    (21193122, 20574624),
    (21194666, 21193122),
    (19770000, 20574624),
    (19681810, 18352628),
    (19931554, 20574624),
    (18382902, 1879450),
    (19780666, 1879450),
    (20631784, 20574624),
]
```

We can represent all the nodes in our tree as `Dict[int, List[int]]` of parent children relationships. The following method can be called on the frame by calling `sort_processes(df.values.tolist())`. The result can be converted back to pandas by calling `pandas.DataFrame(result, columns=['Child', 'Parent'])`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Dict, List, Iterable, Tuple

def sort_processes(processes: List[Tuple[int, int]]) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
    # initialize the nodes
    nodes: Dict[int, List[int]] = defaultdict(list)
    for child, parent in processes:
        nodes[parent].append(child)

    # walk and yield pairs
    def walk_tree(parent: int) -> Iterable[Tuple[int, int]]:
        for child in sorted(nodes[parent]):
            yield (child, parent)
            # avoid infinite loops
            if parent != child:
                yield from walk_tree(child)

    # start at top level parents
    parents = [parent for child, parent in processes if parent == child]
    return list(
        pair for parent in sorted(parents) for pair in walk_tree(parent)
    )
```

Calling `sort_processes(processes)` Returns:

```
[
    (273500, 273500),
    (20574624, 273500),
    (1359996, 20574624),
    (1879450, 20574624),
    (2202652, 1879450),
    (18382902, 1879450),
    (19780666, 1879450),
    (19933526, 1879450),
    (18441258, 20574624),
    (19770000, 20574624),
    (18352628, 19770000),
    (18000796, 18352628),
    (19681810, 18352628),
    (19931554, 20574624),
    (20631784, 20574624),
    (20637582, 20574624),
    (20840426, 20574624),
    (20844632, 20574624),
    (20934910, 20574624),
    (20965442, 20574624),
    (21193122, 20574624),
    (21194666, 21193122),
]
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with vanilla python.

Just to get me started, in my specific case, should I start with    processes = List[ Tuple[ df.['Child'] , df.['Parent'] ]

Also what does this line do: nodes: Dict[int, List[int]] = defaultdict(list)

Comment: Each tuple is a row in the dataframe. Should just be `df.values.tolist()`

Comment: @Eren `defaultdict` is a dictionary where if you query a key that does not yet exist then it will create a new value for you and return it. In this case we use an empty `list` as the returned value. The `: Dict[int, List[int]]` is a type hint. Type hints are purely for allowing tools like mypy to type check your code to avoid bugs. It is a best practice to use them, but they are entirely optional and have no functional impact.