# How to sort data with recursion from the parent first and then proceed to its children using python?

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

I have a model named Topics with data like this:

| id | has_sub_topic | parent_id | subject_module_level_id | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27 | 1 | NULL | 25 | 1 |
| 31 | 1 | NULL | 25 | 2 |
| 34 | 0 | NULL | 25 | 3 |
| 28 | 0 | 27 | 25 | 1 |
| 29 | 0 | 27 | 25 | 2 |
| 40 | 1 | 27 | 25 | 3 |
| 32 | 0 | 31 | 25 | 1 |
| 33 | 0 | 31 | 25 | 2 |
| 41 | 1 | 40 | 25 | 1 |
| 43 | 0 | 40 | 25 | 2 |
| 44 | 1 | 40 | 25 | 3 |
| 42 | 0 | 41 | 25 | 1 |
| 45 | 0 | 44 | 25 | 1 |
| 47 | 1 | 44 | 25 | 2 |
| 48 | 0 | 47 | 25 | 1 |

I Want to sort it by the parent first and then proceed to its children like depth-first processing and get the data only the topics that no has_sub_topic. So, the data will be sorted by order like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Depth-First-Search.gif and get the data only 4, 7, 8, 10

Previously I try using sorted function, but it didn't go well with many child. So, I must use recursive function. My code using recursive is like this:

```js
# Example data for topics
import pandas as pd
topics = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [27, 31, 34, 28, 29, 40, 32, 33, 41, 43, 44, 42, 45, 47, 48], 
    'has_sub_topic': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    'parent_id': [None, None, None, 27, 27, 27, 31, 31, 40, 40, 40, 41, 44, 44, 47],
    'subject_module_level_id': [25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
    'order': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1]
    })
```

```js
def topic_child_order(topic, list_topics=None):
    if list_topics is None: list_topics = []

    if topic.has_sub_topic:
        topics = Topics.objects.filter(parent=topic).order_by('order')
        for child in topics:
            result = topic_child_order(child, list_topics)
    else:
        result = topic

    list_topics.append(result)

    return list_topics
    

topics = Topics.objects.filter(
    subject_module_level_id=25,
    parent=None
).order_by('order')

topics_order = []

for topic in topics:
    topics_order.append(topic_child_order(topic))
```

The result is like this:

```js
[
  [
    <Topics: Topicsobject(28)>,
    <Topics: Topicsobject(29)>,
    <Topics: Topicsobject(42)>,
    [
      ...
    ],
    <Topics: Topicsobject(43)>,
    <Topics: Topicsobject(45)>,
    <Topics: Topicsobject(48)>,
    [
      ...
    ],
    [
      ...
    ],
    [
      ...
    ],
    [
      ...
    ]
  ],
  [
    <Topics: Topicsobject(32)>,
    <Topics: Topicsobject(33)>,
    [
      ...
    ]
  ],
  [
    <Topics: Topicsobject(34)>
  ]
]
```

The sort order is right but I don't know why the result has empty lists. Anyone know how to fix this? Or anyone know how to do this more better way so the result only return in one list not nested list?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with a [mre]? In particular, so that the 15-row table you have shown us is completely defined in the code? See for instancen [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for help. Right now, if I tried to execute your code, I'd just get `NameError: name 'Topics' is not defined`.

Comment: Perhaps you could do: `import pandas as pd; topics = pd.DataFrame({'id': [27, 31, 34, ...], 'parent_id': [...], ...})`. Then, people who read your question can play around with your data, and are much more likely to want to post an answer.

Comment: Okay I added the example data in pd dataframe.

Comment: Similar question: [Sort a column so that one column follows the values from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251758/sort-a-column-so-that-one-column-follows-the-values-from-another-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explicitly built a tree in the form of a nested python dict mapping parent id to list of children ids, using `.iterrows` to add nodes to the tree. Children are sorted using their given order.

Then I perform a simple depth-first-search in the tree, yielding the leaves' ids along the way.

Finally I use `.loc` to select rows in the dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

topics = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [27, 31, 34, 28, 29, 40, 32, 33, 41, 43, 44, 42, 45, 47, 48], 
    'has_sub_topic': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    'parent_id': [0, 0, 0, 27, 27, 27, 31, 31, 40, 40, 40, 41, 44, 44, 47],
    'subject_module_level_id': [25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
    'order': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1]
    }).set_index('id')

tree = {}
for i, row in topics.iterrows():
    tree.setdefault(row['parent_id'], []).append(i)

for brotherhood in tree.values():
    brotherhood.sort(key=lambda sibling: topics.at[sibling,'order'])

# print( tree )
# {0: [27, 31, 34], 27: [28, 29, 40], 31: [32, 33], 40: [41, 43, 44], 41: [42], 44: [45, 47], 47: [48]}

def gen_leaves(tree, i=0):
    if i in tree:
        for child in tree[i]:
            yield from gen_leaves(tree, child)
    else:
        yield i

# print( list(gen_leaves(tree)) )
# [28, 29, 42, 43, 45, 48, 32, 33, 34]

leaf_ids = list(gen_leaves(tree))
topics_leaves = topics.loc[leaf_ids]

print(topics_leaves)
#     has_sub_topic  parent_id  subject_module_level_id  order
# id                                                          
# 28              0         27                       25      1
# 29              0         27                       25      2
# 42              0         41                       25      1
# 43              0         40                       25      2
# 45              0         44                       25      1
# 48              0         47                       25      1
# 32              0         31                       25      1
# 33              0         31                       25      2
# 34              0          0                       25      3
```